# android questions about poping the soft keyboard

Tags: android, soft-input-panel

i want the whole layout move up to show while popping the soft keyboard, but the button on the bottom of the view cannot be seen.

the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
    android:name="cn.duckr.android.plan.PlanConfirmPaymentActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    style="@style/base_activity_style"
    android:theme="@style/confirm_payment_anim_theme" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the system resizes your layout to the available space—which ensures that all of your layout content is accessible (even though it probably requires scrolling)—use "adjustResize".

[link](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html)

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put whole layout except the particular button in a ScrollView to achieve this.

**like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
     <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView5"
        android:fillViewport="true">

            //put your contents here..      
     </ScrollView>

     <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/ibSample"
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```